# Why didn't Harry simply Summon Kreacher to bring them food in the Deathly Hallows?

Tags: harry-potter, food, house-elves

Several times Harry, Ron, and Hermione have had almost nothing to eat:

> The fact that Hermione was getting better at identifying edible fungi could not altogether compensate for their continuing isolation, the lack of other people’s company, or their total ignorance of what was going on in the war against Voldemort. 
>   “My mother,” said Ron on night, as they sat in the tent on a riverbank in Wales, “can make good food appear out of thin air.” 
>   He prodded moodily at the lumps of charred gray fish on his plate.

But why couldn't they simply ask Kreacher to bring them some? I know that in the beginning, he would not have cooperated, but once they gave him Regulus' locket, he would be happy to help. Why would they eat edible fungus when Kreacher would bring them a full meal?

Comment: If you're interested in participating on the site consider registering your accounr, see [Why should I register my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/345161)

Comment: As for the actual question, why risk him giving away their location? Also could they even contact him?

Comment: Well actually the same quote is given here : [Why did Harry and Co. completely ignore the existence of Kreacher?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/114142/98028). Triplicate! :p

Comment: When Harry says Kreacher's name he appears. He does this in the 6th book when he wants him to track Malfoy. And once they make peace with Kreacher, he wouldn't betray them.

Comment: Sure, but war is a bad thing and you can't rule out the possibility of him being tortured/followed to the point he would switch sides, or slip, etc. They were just being cautious - and Hermione's not big on "let's call the elf" anyways.