# Why didn't Harry call Kreacher when they disapparated through the forest?

Tags: harry-potter

When Hermione tried to find an escape, Ron, and Harry side-along disapparated with her to the forest, why didn't Harry call for Kreacher, given the circumstances that the house-elf was now friendlier than ever?

> “As we Disapparated, Yaxley caught hold of me and I couldn’t get rid
>   of him, he was too strong, and he was still holding on when we arrived
>   at Grimmauld Place, and then — well, I think he must have seen the
>   door, and thought we were stopping there, so he slackened his grip and
>   I managed to shake him off and I brought us here instead!” “But then,
>   where’s he? Hang on. . . . You don’t mean he’s at Grimmauld Place? He
>   can’t get in there?” THE THIEF  271  Her eyes sparkled with unshed
>   tears as she nodded. “Harry, I think he can. I — I forced him to let
>   go with a Revulsion Jinx, but I’d already taken him inside the
>   Fidelius Charm’s protection. Since Dumbledore died, we’re
>   Secret-Keepers, so I’ve given him the secret, haven’t I?” There was no
>   pretending; Harry was sure she was right. It was a serious blow. If
>   Yaxley could now get inside the house, there was no way that they
>   could return. Even now, he could be bringing other Death Eaters in
>   there by Apparition. Gloomy and oppressive though the house was, it
>   had been their one safe refuge: even, now that Kreacher was so much
>   happier and friendlier, a kind of home. With a twinge of regret that
>   had nothing to do with food, Harry imagined the house-elf busying
>   himself over the steak-and-kidney pie that Harry, Ron, and Hermione
>   would never eat."
> <sub>***Harry Potter and the Deathly Hollows - Chapter XIV (The Thief)***</sub>

The situations are getting worse than ever. They are being watched as Mr. Weasley said. Yaxley will wonder what's occuring in Grimmauld Place, he could simply check inside the house. Having said that, Death Eaters could torture the house-elf. **They can get a big help from Kreacher especially that the elf can get along with them that time.**

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80689/why-didnt-harry-call-kreacher-to-help-when-in-the-trio-was-captured-in-malfoy-m

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the same chapter that you have quoted:

> He and Hermione had already decided against trying to summon him; what if someone from the Ministry came too? They could not count on elfish Apparition from being free of the same flaw that had taken Yaxley to Grimmauld Place on the hem of Hermione’s sleeve.

Of course that doesn't explain why didn't do it later (say after a few weeks)

Comment: yes it does explain why they wouldn't do it later. How would they know someone from the Ministry wouldn't follow Kreacher to them after a week?

Comment: oh I never read that since I'm not yet finished with the book. Thanks for the information.

Comment: @user13267 Sure a week is risky, but after months? They could have thought of a fool-proof plan to summoun Kreacher after months in wilderness if they wanted to.

Comment: @RedBaron Sure.. they could have Imperiused that person; or killed them or... But the fact remains they were sort of occupied and had to be extremely careful. As it is Harry messed up and got them caught by Snatchers didn't he? And they were forced to apparate along with the Snatchers to Malfoy Manor. Too risky is just that and this is esp true when in war or major conflict. And although self doubt can be a real burden and harmful there are times when it's there to protect you. Which is exactly why user13267 is correct: it does explain why they didn't try it later. Love your handle btw.